# Can we make Entity Framework create simpler sql?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

We're trying to use Entity Framework Code First (5.0) on a legacy database, where we have some problems with a common pattern involving join tables.

For example, a Customer can have multiple Addresses, but the Address table is also used for other types of addresses so there is a join table to link a customer with it's addresses:
Customer -> CustomerAddress -> Address.
The join table CustomerAdress ha a customer-Id and an address-Id.

In our model we only have a Customer class and an Address class, simplified like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

We set up the mapping in OnModelCreating with code like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasMany(o => o.Addresses)
            .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.ToTable("CustomerAddress");
                        m.MapLeftKey("CustomerId");
                        m.MapRightKey("AddressId");
                    });
```

Everything works fine but when we try to do queries on Customer that Include() Addresses the resulting sql looks very complex with a select from a select with multiple joins, and after adding another relation like this the amount of sql kind of explodes.

If hand-coding the sql for this relationship I would use a left outer join from Customer to CustomerAddress and then a join from CustomerAddress to Address.
Is there any way we could make Entity Framework create a simpler sql-statement for this example?

Comment: ***WHY?!?!?*** As long as you get the correct results, within reasonable time - what do you care about what the generated SQL looks like??

Comment: Can you show the SQL it produces?

Comment: @marc_s: Why? Performance! Large chunks of SQL with many joins are hard to optimize for the SQL server engine.

Comment: @Steven - the OP has not suggested that they are experiencing a performance issue.

Comment: @Steven: and you're **sure** it's EF's fault - or could it just be that your database isn't properly optimized (indexed etc.)?

Comment: @marc_s: I've got a lot experience with query tuning and done a lot of tuning of LINQ queries and LINQ generated SQL queries. You are right that you'll of course need the proper indexes and statistics, but sometimes the SQL that EF (or L2S) generates can be very inefficient for SQL server. And when queries get very big and complex, SQL server's query plan will be suboptimal and performance can drop considerably. That doesn't mean though that it is anyone's 'fault'. There are just limitations to the tools we use (EF, SQL, etc) that we have to deal with.

Comment: @Steven: agreed - there are fairly rare cases and circumstances when EF does indeed go astray and the SQL generated *could* be written more efficiently. But I would say this is fairly rare (less than 5-10% of the cases). For the **most part**, the EF generated queries might not *look* nice - but they're at least as efficient as the average programmer's hand-written SQL code. So: unless you actually **experience** a performance issue, my take is: just don't bother about how "bad" the SQL might look like - just use it!

Comment: @marc_s: I agree, in most cases the generated SQL is more than fine. I would even argue that the SQL that EF generates in in *most* cases *more* efficient than what the everage programmer would write. So as always, don't do premature optimizations.

Comment: We are experiencing performance problems, a request to retrieve just one customer takes close to one second on our server. I haven't investigated that deeply if the complex sql really is a big part of the problem, but it looked suspicious. 
The actual code has a number of relations that are Included in the query, and 3-4 of those relations are of this type. The resulting sql is close to 50KB in size.

Comment: Can you show the linq query?